# SQL query returning None in Python script while there are records in table

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to write a simple Python script that gets data from an API, stores it in a MySQL database, and performs some calculations on that data. I try fetch all data from a table where I just inserted some, but that query keeps returning `None`.

Part that doesn't work:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "stijn", "password", "GW2")
curs = db.cursor()
curs.execute("select gw2_id, naam from PrijzenMats")
for record in curs.fetchall():
    curs2 = db.cursor() 
    curs2.execute("insert into MaterialPrijzenLogs(mat,prijs,tijd) values(%s, %s, %s)", (record[1], prijs, tijd))
    db.commit()
    curs2.execute("select prijs from MaterialPrijzenLogs")
    top10 = len(curs2.fetchall())/10
    print(str(len(curs2.fetchall())))
```

That last print keeps giving `0`, even when I populate the table before running the script.

[Full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1QLF.jpg)

Comment: What happens if you execute the query in MySQL?

Comment: It works just fine. It returns all the 'prijs' data from the table as expected. Even when I run the same query from another Python script, it works just fine.

Comment: What do you do differently in the other Python script? Could you provide the working one for comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Apparently when you call `fetchall()` it doesn't just get the data from the cursor like a normal getter in Java would do, but it also deletes the data from the `cursor`. In my code I called `fetchall()` first to initialize a variable, and after that I tried to print the length of `curs2.fetchall()`, which had become `0` at that point. This can be easily solved by adding something like `myList = curs2.fetchall()` directly after `curs2.execute("select prijs from MaterialPrijzenLogs")` and using the `myList` variable in the rest of the code instead of `curs2.fetchall()`. I did not include the declaration of that `top10` variable in the code example in my original question because I thought it had nothing to do with the problem. I edited the question so future readers can easily understand the problem.

Answer (score -2):

> `drop table`

Use drop table whenever you get this none error..

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! `drop table` will just delete your table.